# AJAX PHP Image upload not working, $_FILES empty?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I tried to research pretty much everything already, but I didnt find the final solution to fix my code. As you can see in the debug image, the file prop can be read. In PHP, I the result of `print_r($_FILES); exit;` is an empty array. The problem seems to be `event.preventDefault();`. The submit has to be `prevent` but the file still has to be generated.

JS
[image: Javascript debu]

```js
    $("#cardgeneratorForm").on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var artworkimageinput = $('#inputPicture').prop('files')[0];
        var artworkimage = new FormData();
        artworkimage.append('file', artworkimageinput); 

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'generatecard.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        artworkimage: artworkimage,
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success : function(filename){
                    },
                    fail: function(){
                    }
                });
```

PHP

```php
    <?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'artwork/' . $_FILES['file']['name']); 
    }
```

HTML

```html
<form class="cardgeneratorForm" id="cardgeneratorForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="generatecard.php">
                                    <div class="inputPicture-container custom-file col-12">
                                        <input type="file" name="file" class="custom-file-input" accept='.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .webp' id="inputPicture" lang="en">
                                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputPicture">Card Picture</label>
                                    </div>

     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-xs reset-button">
                                            <span><i class="fas fa-redo"></i>Reset</span>
                                        </button>
</form>
```

Comment: that first 3 lines of code needs to be inside the submit handler

Comment: you are right, they are, i wrote it a bit complicated actualy since the code is alot bigger and i tried to short it to the relevent code. I edited it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do this.

```
$('#cardgeneratorForm').on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        method:$(this).attr('method'), //dynamically getting the method of the form
        url: $(this).attr('action'), //dynamically getting the action of the form
        data:formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("error");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**Start uploading immediately upon file selection (optional)**

```
$("#inputPicture").on("change", function() {
    $("#cardgeneratorForm").submit();
});
```

**I removed some extra brackets and now it's working.**
[image]

Hope it helps!!

Comment: This doesnt help, it has the same result. The preventDefault stops it from working. The $_FILES is still empty.

Comment: @DappFuture I just edited my answer. Check my answer now. There were some extra brackets in the code which I removed and It's working now. There's nothing wrong with `preventDefault` here because it is used here to prevent the normal form submission so we can upload the file through AJAX `asynchronously`.

Comment: I tried it but its not working, i dont know why. Still checking. $_FILES / $_FILES['file']['name'] is empty for me.

Comment: @DappFuture Just recorded a video tutorial for you so you can follow along and make it work. https://youtu.be/xF9Xws5LqwE

Comment: Thank you for the video i didnt expect that. I m not sure yet what is the problem but i outsourced this part to another ajax call and it works the way you wrote it. But inside my existing ajax call it doesnt work, i still have to figur out. But what i didnt mention is that my ajax call is inside this which could cause the problem: "html2canvas(document.getElementById('card-build'),{backgroundColor: null, scrollX: 0, scrollY: -window.scrollY}).then(function(canvas) {"

Comment: Instead of putting your AJAX call inside html2canvas, you can use jQuery promise to take care of it.

Comment: My problem is still not fixed since i have to get it done in one ajax call and so far it works only with 2. The main problem is that the second ajax call that you provided only works with data:formData but i need to give multiple data thats why i use                     data: {
                        formData: formData,
                        filename: filename,
                    }, but with that the $_FILES is an empty array.

Comment: I helped you out with what you posted and If you posted your actual requirement, I would have helped you with that too

Answer (score 0):

use ajaxform plugin, you can find an example here
[example ajaxform](http://hayageek.com/ajax-file-upload-jquery/)

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
         //   document.getElementsByName('userid')[0].value="{{ request.session.user_id }}";
            $(".createnews").click(function(){
                $("#formdata").ajaxForm({target: '#diagshow'});
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: I cant use a plugin like this. My code is abit more complex than what i posted, i just need to fix the image upload the way i tried it in my post.

Comment: i tried before to upload an image+data with ajax but it didnt until i used this js plugin

Comment: My code already includes an image upload and sql insert which works, but the first image upload is through base64 and the second which is just the image from the input isnt working because the php var is empty.

$image = $_POST['image'];
 $location = "card/";
 $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $image);
 $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
file_put_contents($fullfilename, $image_base64);

Comment: yes empty var because to send file via form you need a submit button which does works with ajax,

Comment: Hm yes the problem seems to be "event.preventDefault();" when i delete it it works. But i dont want the form to be submitted it has to be prevented.